# Newline character in bootstrap modal not working.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

How do you properly add a newline for a modal's content? I have a simple string:

```
'Please check the Apple and/or \nOrange Folder checkbox to start program.'
```

I've put the '\n' newline character right before "Orange" so I would expect the modal to have two lines. However, when the modal is displayed, everything is presented on one line (the '\n' is not displayed so I'm sure typescript is seeing it properly and not making it part of the string).

Comment: It shows as you are expecting. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Avar%20message%3A%20string%20%3D%20'Please%20check%20the%20Apple%20and%2For%20%5CnOrange%20Folder%20checkbox%20to%20start%20program.'%0D%0Aalert(message)%0D%0A

Answer (score 18):

> However, when the modal is displayed, everything is presented on one line (the '\n' is not displayed

Make sure the container has CSS `white-space: pre`. Without that newlines are ignored and multiple spaces are collapsed to one etc. This is just how html / CSS works.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. But can u explain what that CSS does?

Comment: "pre" shoved the first line a little to the right, "pre-line" is better for me, as it does not do this.

Answer (score 9):

In my case `white-space: pre-line` worked better then [basarat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390330/basarat) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40881897/5292302) `white-space: pre`.

Comment: THIS! white-space:pre is nice but it stops word wrap in my bootstrap table cells. white-space:pre-line gives you that crucial word wrap

Answer (score 4):

In my case also `white-space: pre-line` or `white-space: pre-wrap` provided the desired result.

Choosing the `white-space: pre` overflowed the modal boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is to use the HTML-tag for a line break: `<br>`
To do that in the context of angular you need to use the innerHTML-Property like this:

```
<p [innerHTML]=" variableIncludingHTML "></p>
```

Here you can find further information:
[Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424375/10076583)